# I can't insert node when I use Python Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy and sqlalchemy_mptt to bulid database table

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

when I try to insert the root node in flask shell, there is something wrong happened

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 553, in commit
    return self._proxied.commit()
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1903, in commit
    trans.commit(_to_root=True)
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 137, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1218, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "<string>", line 2, in _prepare_impl
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 137, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1193, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4155, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4292, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4252, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 467, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 644, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 54, in save_obj
    save_obj(base_mapper, [state], uowtransaction, single=True)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 60, in save_obj
    for (
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 233, in _organize_states_for_save
    mapper.dispatch.before_insert(mapper, connection, state)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 487, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/events.py", line 889, in wrap
    fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy_mptt/events.py", line 574, in before_insert
    mptt_before_insert(mapper, connection, instance)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy_mptt/events.py", line 96, in mptt_before_insert
    select(
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/_selectable_constructors.py", line 493, in select
    return Select(*entities)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 5161, in __init__
    self._raw_columns = [
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 5162, in <listcomp>
    coercions.expect(
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 413, in expect
    resolved = impl._literal_coercion(
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 652, in _literal_coercion
    self._raise_for_expected(element, argname)
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 1143, in _raise_for_expected
    return super()._raise_for_expected(
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 711, in _raise_for_expected
    super()._raise_for_expected(
  File "/Users/pingguo/opt/anaconda3/envs/Flask_Web/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 536, in _raise_for_expected
    raise exc.ArgumentError(msg, code=code) from err
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got [<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x7fee25170d90>]. Did you mean to say select(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x7fee25170d90>)?
```

I think the most import information is this one
[the most important error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpLEp.png)
here is my python code

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy_mptt.mixins import BaseNestedSets


app = Flask(__name__)
url = 'sqlite:////' + os.path.join(app.root_path, 'data.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = url
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False 

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Category(db.Model, BaseNestedSets):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category {}>'.format(self.name)
```

and here is my python package version
[python package version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1WTz.png)
Did that because the version of Flask-SQLAlchemy ?

Follow the most import error tips I find the sqlalchemy_mptt sourcecode in Github
[the error line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fzcm.png)
it seems it will search the table when I try to add a root node, and find out the current biggest tree_id.
If it can be found, the root tree_id will equal to it add 1, if not be found, the root tree_id will equal to 1.
But why this part will have problems, I can't figure out

Comment: Did you get this fixed? Answered?

I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Okay, it seems that we are both using SQLAlchemy 2.0.

Comment: Okay, it seems that we are both using SQLAlchemy 2.0.
Where as sqlalchemy-mptt was last updated 4 years ago - when it was still v. 1.4.

The error seems to stem from the use of Lists in the Select function in sqlalchemy 1.4, and its removal of using lists of argumnets:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html

So... need to update sqlalchemy_mptt to work... basically download it and work with it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it seems that we are both using SQLAlchemy 2.0.
Where as sqlalchemy-mptt was last updated 4 years ago - when it was still v. 1.4.

The error seems to stem from the use of Lists in the Select function in sqlalchemy 1.4, and its removal of using lists of argumnets:
docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html

So... need to update sqlalchemy_mptt to work... basically download it and work with it.

I tested it for my project, simple fix - in most cases just remove the array brackets '[]' in the Select functions. Works like a charm for me now.

Example:

Previously:

```
 select(
      [  
            table.c.lft,
            table.c.rgt
      ] 
    )
```

Change to:

```
 select(
            table.c.lft,
            table.c.rgt
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I will supplement the answer of Cypher_CS.

I managed to fix sqlalchemy_mptt. Now I have sqlalchemy version = 2.0.23

In addition, I had to fix the following table.update().values() (In all places):

```
Previously: connection.execute(table.update().values()
Change to: 
from sqlalchemy import update
connection.execute(update(table).where().values()
```

You also need to change table.delete() in one place. It will turn out like this: delete(table).where()

Do not forget to remove the square brackets (In all places).

```
Previously:
case([(table.c.rgt >= parent_pos_right,
   table.c.rgt + 2
)],
else_=table.c.rgt)

Change to:
case((table.c.rgt >= parent_pos_right,
  table.c.rgt + 2
),else_=table.c.rgt)
```